# Possible to have a deeper zoom on Images in Nautilus?

Tags: 13.10, nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and its Files app. I guess this is Nautilus as well.

When I zoom images I can zoom like 4-5 steps in, but images are still too small to view details.

Can I zoom more levels so I don't have to use external image viewer? I just need to view images at larger zoom.

I am not sure if I am wrong, but I think that before 13.10 Nautilus was able to zoom much deeper.